# C string function calls, pass by value or reference?

Tags: c, string, parameter-passing

I am having trouble figuring out what is going on, I thought C was pass by value but this simple function confuses me with how it works.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void testFunc(char string1[])
 {
   char string2[50] = "the end";
   strcat(string1, string2);
   printf("in func %s \n", string1);
 }

 void main()
 {
    char string1[50] = "the start";
    printf("%IN MAIN %s \n", string1);
    testFunc(string1);
    printf("IN MAIN %s \n", string1);
 }
```

Confusingly the output is:

> IN MAIN thestart
>
> IN FUNC thestarttheend
>
> IN MAIN thestarttheend

So what is going on here? Is C really passing the address of the char array instead of copying the value of it? I thought that is how `char*` would behave not `char[]`

Comment: Note that `void main()` is only valid on Windows; it is not valid on Unix systems.

Comment: You probably meant: `void main()` won't blow up on windows. Only some microcontrollers want that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't pass a copy of an array to a function. When you use the name of an array, it evaluates to a pointer to the 1. element in the array (or as is commonly said, it decays to a pointer.). This happens everywhere except when using the array name in the `sizeof` and `&` operator.

So, you are passing in a pointer to the 1. element of the array to your `testFunc()`

```
 testFunc(string1);
```

is exactly the same as doing

```
 testFunc(&string1[0]);
```

Also, in a function argument list, `char[]` actually means `char *`

These 3 declarations are exactly the same

```
void testFunc(char *string1);
void testFunc(char string1[]);
void testFunc(char string[111]);
```

If you don't want to alter the passed in string, use something like:

e.g.

```
void testFunc(char string1[])
{  
  char string2[50]; 
  const char *end = "the end"; 
  strcpy(string2, string1); 
  strcat(string2, end);
```

(and be awake when using strcpy/strcat, it's easy to overflow arrays doing it like this)

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to preserve the string in the main function how would I have it be unaffected? Do I really have to make a new string and copy that into the function or is there some way to avoid that?

Comment: @PaulthePirate Yes, that's right, you have to allocate storage somewhere. e.g. char string2[50]; char *end = "the end"; strcpy(string2, string1); strcat(string2, end);

Answer (score 6):

C always passes arguments by value, but the string, like other arrays, is converted to a pointer to its first element, and then that pointer is passed. By value.

Answer (score 4):

It is passing by value.

`string1` is the address of the starting position of the `char` array and this value is being passed.

And

```
void testFunc(char string1[])
```

is same as

```
void testFunc(char *string1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of function parameter it is equivalent if you write:-

```
void testFunc(char string1[])

 {
   //body 
 }
```

or

```
void testFunc(char *string1)

 {
     //body
 }
```

in fact in C the first one is always converted to the second type of function defination.So in case of function parameter `N element array of type T` is converted into `Array of type T`,remember it and enjoy C programming.

**NOTE** this only happens in case of function parameters.